# Site images are fixed in front of my site content

Tags: jquery, css, javascript, html

I made an Instagram widget on Codepen.  It works great and it functions on there.  However, when I try adding it to my site it shows up and looks to be working correctly, but I have a ton of the instagram images fixed on my screen in front of my site content (image below).  The instagram widget is appearing to work correctly under all of the images, so now I just need to get the images that pop up on my screen gone.  However, when I look at the console it seems these images are appearing inside the `wp-nav-menu` and my footer elements.  Even though I placed the HTML inside of a post.  I have checked if there are any errors, and it does not say there are any.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could fix this?

EDIT: even if I delete the HTML from anywhere on my site, these images will still appear in front of my content.

codepen - https://codepen.io/elle343/pen/owBoyE

My HTML

```html
<ul id="rudr_instafeed"></ul>
```

my CSS

```html
#rudr_instafeed{
  margin: 42px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center; 
  list-style:none;
}
#rudr_instafeed li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#rudr_instafeed li img{
  max-height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

instagram-footer.js

```html
var token = '5219525.f0b48c7.17327f93adbe4fbb89ccd13a1a226a33',
num_photos = 20;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for( x in data.data ){
            jQuery('ul').append('<li><img src="'+data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url+'"></li>');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

functions.php

```html
function instagramfooter() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'instagramfooter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/instagram-footer.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'instagramfooter' );
```

header.php

```html
<?php
/**
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="ht-page"> 
<header id="ht-masthead" class="ht-site-header">
<div class="ht-container ht-clearfix">
<div id="ht-site-branding">
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'has_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) :
the_custom_logo();
else : 
if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<h1 class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<?php else : ?>
<p class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<p class="ht-site-description"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- .site-branding -->

<nav id="ht-site-navigation" class="ht-main-navigation">
<div class="toggle-bar"><span></span></div>
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'primary', 
'container_class' => 'ht-menu ht-clearfix' ,
'menu_class' => 'ht-clearfix',
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
) ); 
?>
</nav><!-- #ht-site-navigation -->
</div>
</header><!-- #ht-masthead -->
<div id="ht-content" class="ht-site-content ht-clearfix">
```

footer.php

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
    <!-- footer-widgets -->
<div class="footer-widgets clearfix">
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer1')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer1'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer2')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer2'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer3')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer3'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer4')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer4'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- /footer-widgets -->
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
<p id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> 
<?php bloginfo('name');         ?>
</div>
<nav class="footer-nav" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
<?php $args = array( 'theme_location' => 'footer' ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
</nav>

</footer>

</footer>

</div><!-- container -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

front-page.php

```html
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: 
*/ 

get_header(); 
get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
               'posts_per_page' => 15, 
               'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?> 

</div> 
<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { 
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
get_footer();
```

functions.php

```html
<?php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
function btc_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.7' );
        wp_enqueue_script ( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true);
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'btc_scripts' );

//Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));
class CSS_Menu_Walker extends Walker {

var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
global $wp_query;
$indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
$class_names = $value = '';
$classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
/* Add active class */
if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
$classes[] = 'active';
unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
}
/* Check for children */
$children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
if (!empty($children)) {
$classes[] = 'has-sub';
}
$class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
$class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';
$id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args);
$id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';
$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
$attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';
$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</span></a>';
$item_output .= $args->after;
$output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
}
function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$output .= "</li>\n";
}
}


// Add Widget Areas
function ourWidgetsInit() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 1',
        'id' => 'footer1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 2',
        'id' => 'footer2',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 3',
        'id' => 'footer3',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 4',
        'id' => 'footer4',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsInit');

// Theme setup
function learningWordpress_setup() {
// Navigation Menus    
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));


// Add featured image support
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('medium-thumbnail', 446, 345, true);
    add_image_size('large-thumbnail', 1386, 595, true);
    add_image_size('popular-posts', 256, 256, true);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'learningWordpress_setup');
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function location() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Locations',
        'singular_name'              => 'Location',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Location',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
        'view_item'                  => 'View Item',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate items with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove items',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular Items',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
        'no_terms'                   => 'No items',
        'items_list'                 => 'Items list',
        'items_list_navigation'      => 'Items list navigation',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'post' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'location', 0 );
// Carousel
function carousel_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl.carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'effects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/effects.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carousel_scripts' );
// Custom control for carousel category

if (class_exists('WP_Customize_Control')) {
    class WP_Customize_Category_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {

        public function render_content() {

            $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( 
                array(
                    'name'              => '_customize-dropdown-category-' . $this->id,
                    'echo'              => 0,
                    'show_option_none'  => __( '&mdash; Select &mdash;' ),
                    'option_none_value' => '0',
                    'selected'          => $this->value(),

                )
            );

            $dropdown = str_replace( '<select', '<select ' . $this->get_link(), $dropdown );

            printf(
                '<label class="customize-control-select"><span class="customize-control-title">%s</span> %s</label>',
                $this->label,
                $dropdown
            );
        }
    }
}

// Register slider customizer section 

add_action( 'customize_register' , 'carousel_options' );

function carousel_options( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_section(
    'carousel_section',
    array(
        'title'     => 'Carousel settings',
        'priority'  => 202,
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'carousel_setting',
     array(
    'default'   => '',
  )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_category_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'carousel_category',
        array(
            'label'    => 'Category',
            'settings' => 'carousel_setting',
            'section'  => 'carousel_section'
        )
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'count_setting',
     array(
    'default'   => '6',

  )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'carousel_count',
        array(
            'label'          => __( 'Number of posts', 'theme_name' ),
            'section'        => 'carousel_section',
            'settings'       => 'count_setting',
            'type'           => 'text', 
        )
    )
);

}

//JQUERY

function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/loadmore.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
//MORE J

function my_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', plugin_dir_url(' /js/fontend.min.js' ) . '/js/fontend.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
//MORE COMMENTS
/**
 * Return the default comment form fields.
 *  Customize comment form default fields.
 * Move the comment_field below the author, email, and url fields.
 */
function wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields( $fields ) {
    $commenter     = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $user          = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_identity = $user->exists() ? $user->display_name : '';
    $req           = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req      = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    $fields = [
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( '', 'textdomain'  ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required"></span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="245"' . $aria_req . $html_req . ' /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( '', 'textdomain'  ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required"></span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="email" name="email" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="email"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="100" aria-describedby="email-notes"' . $aria_req . $html_req  . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( '', 'textdomain'  ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="url" name="url" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="url"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="200" /></p>',

    ];

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields' );

/**
 * Remove the original comment field because we've added it to the default fields
 * using wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields(). If we don't do this, the comment
 * field will appear twice.
 */
function wpse250243_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {
    if ( isset( $defaults[ 'comment_field' ] ) ) {
        $defaults[ 'comment_field' ] = '';
    }

    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse250243_comment_form_defaults', 10, 1 );
//MOVE COMMENTS
function wpb_move_comment_field_to_bottom( $fields ) {
$comment_field = $fields['comment'];
unset( $fields['comment'] );
$fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'wpb_move_comment_field_to_bottom' );
//COMMENTS
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse_62742_comment_placeholders' );

/**
 * Change default fields, add placeholder and change type attributes.
 *
 * @param  array $fields
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_62742_comment_placeholders( $fields )
{
    $fields['author'] = str_replace(
        '<input',
        '<input placeholder="'
        /* Replace 'theme_text_domain' with your theme’s text domain.
         * I use _x() here to make your translators life easier. :)
         * See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x
         */
            . _x(
                'Name',
                'comment form placeholder',
                'theme_text_domain'
                )
            . '"',
        $fields['author']
    );
    $fields['email'] = str_replace(
        '<input id="email" name="email" type="text"',
        /* We use a proper type attribute to make use of the browser’s
         * validation, and to get the matching keyboard on smartphones.
         */
        '<input type="email" placeholder="Email"  id="email" name="email"',
        $fields['email']
    );
    $fields['url'] = str_replace(
        '<input id="url" name="url" type="text"',
        // Again: a better 'type' attribute value.
        '<input placeholder="Website" id="url" name="url" type="url"',
        $fields['url']
    );



    return $fields;
}
//Comments Continued
if ( get_option ('thread_comments') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
}
//Comments
function custom_comments ($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
  <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
      <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
          <header class="comment-author-vcard">


              <?php printf (__('<cite_class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says"></span>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>
    </header>



          <div class="comment-meta"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID )) ?>"></a></div>

          <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
          <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
          <?php endif; ?>

              <div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text() ?></div>

          <div class="comment-time"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'), '   ', ' ') ?><?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ))) ?></div>                           



          <div class="reply">

          </div>
      </div>
          <?php
}
//New Menus
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'new-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu Secondary' ),
      'another-menu' => __( 'Another Menu' ),
      'an-extra-menu' => __( 'An Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
// Wordpress
function load_fonts() {
            wp_register_style('et-googleFonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=David+Libre|Crimson+Text|Questrial|Raleway:200,300,400,600,700|Montserrat|Catamaran|Pathway+Gothic+One|PT+Serif|Days+One|Lato:300,400,700|Work+Sans:400,500,600,700');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts');
        }
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
//REMOVE P
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p>\\s*?(<a .*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');

// Popular Posts
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) { 
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count'; 
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true); 
if($count==''){ 
$count = 0; 
delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key); 
add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, 0); 
}else{ 
$count++; 
update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count); 
} 
} 
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching 
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) { 
if ( !is_single() ) return; 
if ( empty ( $post_id) ) { 
global $post; 
$post_id = $post->ID; 
} 
wpb_set_post_views($post_id); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
//search
 function searchfunction() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'searchfunction' );
//hamburger menu
 function hamburgermenu() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'hamburger-menu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/hamburgermenu.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hamburgermenu' );
 //instagram footer
 function instagramwidget() {
          wp_enqueue_script ( ‘instagramfooter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/instagram-footer', array('jquery'), '2.2.4', true);
}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', ‘instagramfooter' );
```

screenshot of problem
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the widget outside of WP in a locally served static document? Do you have the problem there? If not look at the menu creation markup of your theme and see if there are class names that are shared perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I have it on a local host, if that is what you mean.  I have no class names that are shared.

Comment: Perhaps show the part of the markup that creates the nav menu, in functions.php and in the template file, i.e. heaper.php. Include the resulting HTML source, the part where the images are inside the wp-nav-menu. Since that is what is happening, perhaps the nav menu is in a loop or array and the images are hence loaded too often?

Comment: I've added a few more of my files like the header and footer php files.

Comment: You seem to be broadly appending to _any and all unordered lists_ on the page `jQuery('ul')`, no wonder you get images all over. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It quite looks like your Instagram script is appending the images to each `ul` and since the nav menu has a `ul` class in its structure the images appear there.

Try appending the images to a specific placeholder class with your script instead of the `ul` and let me know if that helped.

`jQuery('.instagram').append(`

Since you changed the place where the images appear from `ul` to `instagram` you now also have to create a div with `instagram` in your HTML.

Leave the jQuery like seen above.
See if the images appear only inside the newly created `instagram` div.
If they do place the `instagram` div where you want the feed to appear in your HTML markup.

Comment: Is the jQuery('ul.instagram').append( the only thing I should be changing?  I changed it to ul.instagram, and the images that were on top of my content have disappeared, but now the instagram widget has also disappeared. (i also tried your edit of .instagram)

Comment: Create a new div class `instagram` in your HTML at a random place. Leave the jQuery with the current edit. See if the images appear only there. If they do place the `instagram` div where you want the feed to appear in your HTML markup.

Comment: So instead of <ul id="instagram-footer"></ul> I should use <div class="instagram"></div>, correct?

Comment: Yes. And if you only ever have the images come up **once** on each page you could also use `div id="instagram"></div>`, but generally, yes, where you script `append`s the fetched images there needs to be a matching place for it in your markup, you can call it anything that does not interfere with markup used by WordPress, like it happened in the nav menu, it having a `ul` class and that also being triggered by your script.

Comment: I can not thank you enough, it worked! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Remember if you change the placeholder to an ID in the HTML to also make that change in the script. Otherwise leave it as a class and be safe. Glad it worked out.